# bash: separating command from pipe

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, pipe, command-line-arguments

I have a third-part software that accepts command line arguments. I want to pipe the output in a file. I have found that for some inexplicable reasons the code hangs if I try:

```
./run_third_part.py &> log
```

but it works if

```
./run_third_part.py
```

I believe that  piping the output is messing up with the process of reading command line arguments, although other ideas are welcome. How can I isolate the program from the pipe command? (I was thinking about putting some sort of parentheses.)

Comment: Does this program read anything from the input?

Comment: it does, but it can also take no input

Comment: You say "accepts command line arguments". Where are you specifying these?

Comment: it does, but they are optional

Answer (score 0):

Probably the script is waiting for input on an interactive prompt. The easiest way around this is usually to give it some input:

```
./run_third_part.py < /dev/null &> log
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try creating a subshell and run the script,

```
bash$ `./run_third_part.py` &> log
```

Please notice ` is not '
 (single quote)

Comment: Do not. This answer is wrong and - depending of the output of run_third_part.py - could be dangerous.

Comment: I have tried a similar scenario in the local system and verified, come to a conclusion that running it in a subshell and take the entire content in log could also work.
Please explain how it could be dangerous,

Comment: So, try to run a command: `\`echo ls\``. And then do a backup of current directory and replace `ls` with `rm *`.

Comment: Within the subshell the commands will execute, now what is the relation of that with invoking a script in a subshell.

Comment: Because backquotes are not for running the command in a subshell. Yes, they do that, *as a side effect*. `echo rm *` is completely harmless command. You can safely run it in your shell. However, put that in backquotes, and you will lost your data. Try it if you don't believe. Or, better, read the documentation carefully.